# MySQL,Create table using data from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Could you help me with designing a MySQL query for creating a table with data from other 3 tables?

Database design:

[image]

What I have tried was:

```
INSERT INTO SklepZaloha (TIME)
    SELECT TIME FROM Item1;
INSERT INTO SklepZaloha (Boiler)
    SELECT Value FROM Item1;
INSERT INTO SklepZaloha (Zpatecka)
    SELECT Value FROM Item2;
INSERT INTO SklepZaloha (Vymnenik)
    SELECT Value FROM Item3;
```

But that results in: a a a b b b c c c instead of: a b c a b c a b c

Comment: Yes, I guess we could help you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: We need to know what is on the other tables and if it is columns and/or rows that you need to copy and merge. Also, what entries have top priority and which ones have least priority.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use:

INSERT INTO SklepZaloha (TIME) SELECT TIME FROM Item1;
INSERT INTO SklepZaloha (Boiler) SELECT Value FROM Item1;
INSERT INTO SklepZaloha (Zpatecka) SELECT Value FROM Item2;
INSERT INTO SklepZaloha (Vymnenik) SELECT Value FROM Item3;

But that results in:

a
a
a
  b
  b
  b
    c
    c
    c

instead of:

a b c
a b c
a b c

So it will create null records until the last value from the first INSERT.

Comment: Can the data from the source tables be joined? If yes, how?

Comment: I need to export CSV data in Time, Boiler, Zpatecka, Vymnenik Format. So i figured out, that i need to create table, which I will export. After filling the export table and exporting the csv file, I need to delete all the records in Item1, Item2, Item3 and the export table.

Comment: You do not necessarily have to create a table, select into outfile works with a query as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `INSERT ... SELECT` needs to insert the entire row at once, not nibble away one value at a time. To do this, you need to use a `JOIN`.

```
INSERT INTO SklepZaloha
    (`Time`, Boiler, Zpatecka, Vymnenik)
  SELECT i1.`Time`, i1.Value, i2.Value, i3.Value
    FROM Item1 i1
    INNER JOIN Item2 i2
      ON i1.`Time` = i2.`Time`
    INNER JOIN Item3 i3
      ON i1.`Time` = i3.`Time`;
```

The **`SELECT`** portion would also be the correct syntax for a **`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`** query.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Now i need to figure out the CSV format export.

Answer (score -1):

I can tell you one thing, you're going to have to use a prepared statement in a stored procedure in all likelihood.  It's been some time since I've done this, but within a stored procedure you can access the tables with the data and then construct a prepared statement that you then execute.

The MySQL documentation on stored procedures as well as prepared statements is pretty good.

I do vaguely remember, however, there being an issue with executing statements of this type in a stored procedure.

Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Michael

Comment: 1. You do not need a stored procedure for this. 2. Select into outfile will not work in a stored procedure anyway.